# Anime about the cameraman from a television show

Tags: love-love

I'm trying to remember the title of an anime I watched a while back. I watched this anime sometime in 2007. Judging by what little I remember of the art style the anime was probably made sometime between 2000 and 2005. The episodes were 10-15 minutes each and there were about 10 of them. The show had a lot of nudity and was pretty explicit, but I'm sure it wasn't hentai. I somehow remember the plot very vividly despite forgetting the name. It wasn't a very good show, but I'd still like to know what it was.

The anime was about producing some sort of hero/sentai television show. In that fictional television show there were several girls (probably 5) who were able to transform into different outfits and gain different abilities depending on their outfit. The main character is a high school boy who is the camera man for the show who is secretly also the writer of the show. He's also pretty perverted, and a lot of the show is just him falling into erotic delusions.

The actresses playing the characters in the sentai show realize that he is actually the writer, though they keep this a secret from him. Somehow they all go to his school (I think), even though I'm pretty sure some of them were elementary- or middle-schoolers. In order to try to increase their screen-time, they all start trying to seduce him by getting into compromising situations, like "accidentally" running into him naked or showing him their underwear. The first half (maybe more) of the series is just random fanservice in that vein.

Later on, he figures out that they know that he is the writer and that they've been seducing him, and decides to punish them by putting them into even more embarrassing situations, causing wardrobe malfunctions on-stage and doing all sorts of other abuses of power. The series takes a sort of darker turn at this point, though there's still plenty of fanservice. However, the plan backfires on him. Some sort of controversy causes him to be taken off the project, and I think the show was even cancelled. Yet somehow there was a happy ending where all the actresses were still friendly with him and the show gets restarted, and he might end up in a relationship with one of the girls. The only thing I remember about the ending is that it was rather implausible, so I don't know how that happened.

Does anyone have any idea what this anime could be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the show *[LOVE♥LOVE?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Love%3F)*.

> Naoto Ohizumi is the screenwriter for the all-female Super Sentai TV show, The Super Transforming Cosmopolitan Prayers ("Cosplayers"), although this is only known by the show's producer. Naoto has a crush on one of the show's stars, Natsumi Yagami. As the show proceeds so does their relationship, with many twists and turns along the way. Many of the other actresses are also in love with Naoto, creating various situations throughout the anime.

Comment: Yup, that's the one.